# Java ScheduledExecutorService wait until a resource is available

Tags: java, multithreading, runnable, callable

I have a problem with my java application. On the startup of the application the application needs a connection to another application. My idea was to check on startup of my application to check every second if the other application is available (no condition like wait 5 Minutes, just wait infinitly until available).

I tryed this in the abstract example shown below. In the excample my application will get the other application after 3 trys ...

```
package main;

import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.concurrent.CancellationException;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledFuture;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;

public class Main {

    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(Main.class);


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final Callable<String> sleeper = new Callable<String>() {

            // local timer for resource getter
            ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
            ScheduledFuture<?> timer;

            String returnValue;

            @Override
            public String call() throws Exception {

                // start on first call
                if (null == timer) {
                    logger.info("sleeper - starting getter ...");
                    timer = executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(new getter(3), 0, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                }

                // the right way - this seems to be ugly!
                try {
                    timer.get(); 
                } catch (CancellationException | ExecutionException | InterruptedException e) {
                    logger.error("sleeper - got an exception ... but nothing bad?!");
                }

                logger.info("sleeper - returning="+returnValue);
                return returnValue;
            }

            class getter implements Runnable {
                int _trys;
                int _maxTrys;
                String _res = null;

                getter(int maxTrys) {
                    logger.info("getter - init, maxTrys=" + maxTrys);
                    _maxTrys=maxTrys;
                }
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    if (null == _res) {
                        if (_trys<_maxTrys) {
                            ++_trys;
                            logger.info("getter - sleeping trys="+_trys + "/" + _maxTrys);
                        } else {
                            _res = "*MIGHTY RESOURCE*";
                            logger.info("getter - found resource after "+_trys+" trys!");
                        }
                    } else {
                        logger.info("getter - returning resource to parent");
                        returnValue = _res; // hand over
                        this.notify(); // exit?
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        logger.info("Main - starting sleeper");
        ScheduledExecutorService sleeperExecutor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
        Future<String> resource = sleeperExecutor.submit(sleeper);
        try {
            logger.info("Main - got="+resource.get());
        } catch (ExecutionException | InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

This seems to be a bad solution for me because I can only exit with an exception (see timer.get()). And it seems to be very mich code for such a simple problem.

I imagine something like this (pseudo code):

```
Application {
    start() {

        while (!otherAppl.isAvailable) {
            // wait until other appl is available
        }

        // other application is available ... go on with startup
    }
}
```

Regards
S.

Comment: What is the resource that you're trying to connect to? A database, a web server, a message-bus, etc?

Comment: There are a few resouces but the main resource is a database.

Comment: Assumption: the database server is hosted elsewhere and you're not trying to start it. I'd just use a database connection pool (eg [HikariCP](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP) ) and assume at app start time everything is okay. Ie I wouldn't write any special `start()` code. For the lifetime your app's process is alive, the DB may be inaccessible at any time for any reason - so I don't think there's any special reason to check connectivity on app start. Hope that makes sense.